# const char * is incompatible with parameter of type char *, initgraph()

Tags: c++, bgi

I have been going through this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/draw-circle-c-graphics/ and for some reason it seems to not be working, I'm using vs 2019, I have the dependency's, no errors there, it seems its just the two quotes in `initgraph(&gd, &gm, "");`

> error: E0167 argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *"

Comment: That's because the code is in C and you're trying to compile it as C++. These are different languages.

Comment: I believe you need an old version of mingw to use this c code from 2005 that is a port of a 1980s / 1990s graphics library from turbo c.

Comment: Honestly, you shouldn't waste time trying to learn C++ at that site (even though the code is C, their C++ examples are almost always poorly written), waste time using a compiler that is almost 30 years old (Turbo C++), and waste time learning an outdated graphics system such as BGI, when there are modern systems you could learn that has value to them.

Comment: CodingWiz, take drescherjm's warning very seriously. Unless you've dug fairly deep in the search results when looking for a BGI library you'll have been pointed at codecutter's port, and that sucker was written for GCC 3 (GCC is on 11), Windows XP, and the graphics hardware and drivers of the time. If your computer is relatively up-to-date you can get the code exactly right and your program still might not work. If you MUST use BGI, [here's a link to an updated port](http://libxbgi.sourceforge.net/), but Paul's right. You're learning to fight tanks with a bronze-tipped spear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument to `initgraph` should be a `char*` but in C++, `""` is a `const char[1]`.

```
void initgraph(int *graphdriver, int *graphmode, char *pathtodriver);
```

You can get around that problem by creating a `char[1]` and use that as an argument instead:

```
char pathtodriver[] = "";
initgraph(&gd, &gm, pathtodriver);
```

Comment: hmm once I did that, it didint throw anything else but now there is a new error: int right: redefinition.

Comment: links to this: `void printimage(
    const char* title=NULL, 
    double width_inches=7, double border_left_inches=0.75, double border_top_inches=0.75,
    int left=0, int right=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX,
    bool active=true, HWND hwnd=NULL
    );` int right=INT_MAX is the problem

Comment: @CodingWiz You have _two_ `right` in that line - there can be only one! :-)

Comment: hmm, so which one should I use?

Comment: @CodingWiz It's impossible for us to say. Please update your question with a [mre] if you don't think that this answer has answered the question you initially asked.

Comment: Ted, is it time for The Gathering already?

Comment: turns out I have an old version of the library's so lets hope thats it :/

Comment: Holy ground @user4581301 - Remember what Ramirez taught you! :-)

Comment: @CodingWiz Everything is old about that library. You should probably upgrade to a new development environment, but that's not the problem with your `printimage` above. You can't have two function parameters with the same name.

Comment: hmm what do ya recommend for a new dev enviroment?

Comment: That depends on a lot of things. For Windows you have Visual Studio and C++Builder + a lot of others (mingw etc). For posix systems, `g++`, `clang++` etc. You'll also need a modern graphics library but I can't say much about that since I don't do graphics myself, but `SDL_bgi` could perhaps make the transition from your old library easy.

Comment: Hmm, I think I might try opengl, but first imma try SDL_bgi

Comment: oh I didint mean to XD idk what happened there :/